# Issues when unit testing .net Core app in Azure Dev Ops

Tags: unit-testing, azure-devops, asp.net-core-2.2, vs-unit-testing-framework

I have a .net core 2.2 project, with some unit tests that test a class library project using Visual Studio Testing

Visual Studio Test - YAML

```
steps:
  - task: VSTest@2
  displayName: 'VsTest - testAssemblies'
  inputs:
    testAssemblyVer2: |
      **\*test*.dll
     !**\*TestAdapter.dll
     !**\obj\**
     **\$(BuildConfiguration)\*\*unittests.dll
     **\$(BuildConfiguration)\*\*test*.dll
     !**\*Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform*
  vstestLocationMethod: location
  vstestLocation: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Extensions\TestPlatform\'
  codeCoverageEnabled: true
  otherConsoleOptions: '/Framework:.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.2 /logger:console;verbosity="normal"'
  platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
  configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
  timeoutInMinutes: 1
```

And the error message

### [warning]No test assemblies found matching the pattern:

***test*.dll,!***TestAdapter.dll,!**\obj**,**\Release**unittests.dll,**\Release**test*.dll,!***Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform*.

Can anyone identify what needs to be done to make it work?

I have tried various different options for the above

Comment: what's your test project name?

Comment: Wintegrate.Tests.csproj

Comment: Set system.debug variable to true, then queue build and share the log.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to be pointing to the projects themselves; not the output DLL's.

So your pattern needs to look more like this: `**/*[Tt]ests/*.csproj`

Which will cause DEV Ops to load all projects that have `Tests` in its Project Name

[image]

Comment: Ok i now get:   Unable to find d:\a\1\s\Wintegrate.MSTest\Wintegrate.MSTest.deps.json. Make sure test project has a nuget reference of package "Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk".  And yes that project is referenced

Comment: Ah ok, are you missing tasks in your queue? Theres a certain stack of things you have to do to restore packages, build and THEN test your build. They need to be done in a certain order for it to work. I know its fiddly.. I've updated the answer with an example of the task order that I have working

Comment: I have checkout, restore and build tasks before the test and still get that same error

Comment: Ok I have now switched my task from VsTest to .net core as per your screen shot.  it now finds the test and runs them with the tests failing (the tests pass fine when running locally).    Failed   Wintegrate.Tests.HelperTests.ToLocalTime
Error Message:
 Assert.Equal() Failure
          ↓ (pos 0)
Expected: 04/07/2019 12:26:10
Actual:   7/4/2019 11:26:10 AM
          ↑ (pos 0)  (There are also a number of other failures such as expected OK Actual 0

Comment: Perfect, that means it works. Your unit test is just failing now. Thats something you'll need to address in development and re-commit to fix. In this case, the server might have a different time to what you're expecting. Try to avoid using ToLocalTime and use an actual "const" instead

Comment: The unit tests are working fine in dev mode, im just getting datatype missmatches in VSTS